# If first condition or zero condition?

Tags: word-choice, conditionals, first-conditional

I saw these two sentences and was wondering which one is right,
1) If you are a well-organized person you manage your time.
2) If you are a well-organized person you will manage your time.
I know zero condition is used for facts, so I say it should be the right one, others don’t agree, please help.
Edit: I saw this: http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf
Now I know it’s ‘wrong’ to say zero, first conditionals bit still I need to know which one is right.

Comment: I say neither is right. Certainly a well-organized person won't need to manage their time at all. They will always have lots and lots of time to spare thanks to being so well-organized.

Comment: Maybe, but I looked to this from a different point of view, I think if he manages his time, he will be well organized, so I suppose it’s not about logic, cause every one can see it differently, I need a grammatical explanation.